# D3DCompileFromFile giving "E_NOTIMPL" hr error - C++/DirectX

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, directx-11

I've been trying to create a compute shader but can't for the life of me figure out what the heck E_NOTIMPL means, the documentation is the most vague thing I've ever seen and everyone I've seen with the problem has a separate solution to it ranging from OS re-installs to clearing out temp files from AppData, so here is my version of this problem.

Whenever I try to run this program it doesn't compile the shader file, the HR returns "E_NOTIMPL" and I have absolutely no idea why, I've tried including all the directories from the DirectCompute Basic Samples projects I've been studying, and despite copying all of its project settings it refuses to work.

Here is my CompileShaderFromFile function which runs D3DCompileFromFile

```
HRESULT CompileShaderFromFile(const WCHAR* szFileName, LPCSTR szEntryPoint, LPCSTR szShaderModel, ID3DBlob** ppBlobOut)
{
    if (!ppBlobOut)
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    // find the file
    WCHAR str[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT hr = FindDXSDKShaderFileCch(str, MAX_PATH, szFileName);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    // Set the D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG flag to embed debug information in the shaders.
    // Setting this flag improves the shader debugging experience, but still allows 
    // the shaders to be optimized and to run exactly the way they will run in 
    // the release configuration of this program.
    dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;

    // Disable optimizations to further improve shader debugging
    dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#endif

    ID3DBlob* pErrorBlob;;

#if D3D_COMPILER_VERSION >= 46

    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(str, nullptr, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, szEntryPoint, szShaderModel,
        dwShaderFlags, 0, ppBlobOut, &pErrorBlob);


#else

    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(str, nullptr, nullptr, szEntryPoint, szShaderModel,
        dwShaderFlags, 0, nullptr, ppBlobOut, &pErrorBlob, nullptr);

#endif

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (pErrorBlob)
            OutputDebugStringA((char*)pErrorBlob->GetBufferPointer());

        SAFE_RELEASE(pErrorBlob);

        return hr;
    }

    SAFE_RELEASE(pErrorBlob);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Here is where I try to compile a compute shader calling CompileFromFile

```
HRESULT CreateResources()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    ID3DBlob* pBlob = nullptr;

    LPCSTR profile = (g_pd3dDevice->GetFeatureLevel() >= D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0) ? "cs_5_0" : "cs_4_0";
    // Compile the Ray Rendering Compute Shader
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile(L"ExampleCompute.hlsl", "RenderRay", profile, &pBlob);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;
```

And finally here is the entry point of my compute shader

```
groupshared uint things;
[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void RenderRay(uint3 Gid : SV_GroupID, uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID, uint3 GTid : SV_GroupThreadID, uint GI : SV_GroupIndex)
{
    float4 empty = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    float4 result = trace(empty, raydir, 0);
    Data[0] = ToFloat3(result);


}
```

Please ask if you need any more insight into my problem, thank you very much in advance.

UPDATE: I definitely remember the example I was following working on my computer, but now even that won't work with D3DCompileFromFile and I literally haven't changed anything in there, very confused.

UPDATE 2: I re-downloaded the sample project and it once again works, although I can't remember changing anything about it...

UPDATE 3: I've gotten it working, it turns out it was giving me an error in the compiler about having a recursive function which apparently isn't allowed, but that doesn't explain what went wrong with the sample project so I'm hesitant to mark it as an answer....

Comment: Trying building the shader with the command-line and see what kind of errors you get.

Comment: Can you look at what version of the compiler dll you are using ? the most recent one is version 47